# What is the meaning of "a correspondence of principles"?

Tags: meaning, expressions, word-usage

Which are the uses and meanings of this expression?

From my own research, it seems to have:

- In politics, a formal meaning close of *agreement* or *treaty*: "a correspondence of principles was sign secretly in Oslo."
- In a more informal or figurative context, I felt it sound like *guideline* or *motto*.

However, I am pretty sure this is quite incomplete.

Answer (score 2):

It **could** mean an exchange of letters about principles, but it could also refer to a kind of matching of principles. It depends on the context.